# How can I remove a class from certain position?

Tags: jquery, hover, position, removeclass

I have this function

```
$('*').hover(

    function (e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
        $(elem).addClass('hoverElem');

    },
    function (e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
        $(elem).removeClass('hoverElem');
    }
);
```

this works fine with the first function but the second function doesnt do any thing, any ideas how can i fix it?

Comment: Can't you just use $(this).xxxClass('hoverElem');

Comment: NO, that doesnt do what i want.

Comment: It may be helpful then if you actually explain what it is that you want.

Comment: I think that when the second function is called, the pointer is no longer on the same element (else that function would not be triggered). So perhaps remove all classes before adding the new one.

Comment: I second that, by the time the hover out happens the mouse has already left the element so you are removing the class from a different element (that probably didn't have the class to begin with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('*').hover(
    function (e) {
        // Remove class from previous element
        $('.hoverElem').removeClass('hoverElem');

        // Add class to new element
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
        $(elem).addClass('hoverElem');
    }
);
```

or this:

```
$('*').hover(
    function (e) {
        // Add class to new element
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
        $(elem).addClass('hoverElem');
    }, function (e) {
        // Remove class from previous element
        $('.hoverElem').removeClass('hoverElem');
    }
);
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so it's a bit hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution:

```
$('*').hover(
function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('hoverElem');
},
function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('hoverElem');
}
);
```